# Autowired beans into java List, and mock it

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, autowired

Most of you probably will say that I should google it, since it's quite simple, but I can't find a truly correct solution that works.

There is one class that use `ArrayList` of specific objects that implement a interface.

The first problem is that actually in the list there is only one item.

The bean definition (There is only one bean that currently implement this interface):

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype") 
public class MC implements IMC 
{ ... }
```

The class with the `@Autowired`:

```
@Component
public class CheckM {   

    private List<IMC> MCsList;

    @Autowired
    public void setMCsList(List<IMC> MCsList)
    {
        this.MCsList = MCsList;
    } 
    ...
}
```

When I check `MCsList` there is only one item (`MCsList.get(0)`) that have been initialized. 
How can I initialize more items in the list (of course without `new`, but by Autowired)?

The second challenge is how can I mock this list with Mockito and inject it to `CheckM` for `CheckM`'s unit-testing.

Thank you.

Comment: You have only 1 element on list because you defined only one bean of type ICM. When you define more components, for example class MC2, then the list will be populated with more elements

Comment: @michaldo, thank you. Now I'm understanding the logic, but how can I populate more items with other instances of the same bean?

Comment: Quite simply: define multiple classes that implement IMC. By default, Spring will name such beans using the implementation's class name. All of them will be autowired as you desire. One note though: please use Constructor injection instead of setters/field injection. It is a much cleaner way to specify on which collaborators your component depends on.

Comment: In http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-bean-annotation you see example how bean is defined by method. If you clone the method 3 times (and provide different method names) you will get 3 beans which are instances of the same class

Comment: Anyway one issues comes to my mind. Why MC is a prototype? When CheckM is singleton then MC is effectively singleton also. Maybe you use MC somewhere else, but often injection prototype into singleton means wrong understandung bean scope

Comment: In addition to the other comments which are spot-on, you generally shouldn't mock a list with Mockito. Just create a real list with `Arrays.asList` or similar.

Comment: @R4J, thank you. Maybe I didn't clearly explain my question. I want list that populated with different instances of the same class. Define multiple classes that implement IMC doesn't answer it.

Comment: @michaldo, thank you. MC is prototype and CheckM doesn't, because of the same reason. I want singleton that contain list of non-singleton class instances. In the link of Spring documents, there is example that use 'new' of specific implementation. I search for autowired to avoid of using specific implementation.

Comment: @yoni still. You can create multiple beans of the same type. Just in your case you will have to give them unique names and then my comment still applies.